# In Visual Studio Code Ctrl+V is not working

Tags: copy-paste, visual-studio-code, ctrl

In Visual Studio Code **`Ctrl+V`** is not working on editor.

 However from the command palette **`Ctrl+Shift+V`** is working.

Comment: Look up what Ctrl+V is bound to in the keyboard shortcuts.  [Gear icon/Keyboard shortcuts] - search for "ctrl+V" anything there that would conflict with paste?

Comment: @Mark you are right there was a conflict issue, you can put in answer if you want to so i can select it

Comment: Ensure that an added extension is not the root cause. Disable them all, then turn one at a time back on. Good luck!

Comment: This bit me hard with Jupyter notebooks in vsCode - paste is remapped, it seems!

Comment: in my VSCode settings is fine. ctrl+a and ctrl+z is working, but ctrl+c and ctrl+v is wrong.  rebooting VSCode is helped me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@WebD'is answer is very helpful and I have upvoted it.  But my comment focused on whether there was a conflicting binding for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and how to find it.  You can literally type "`Ctrl+V`"  (note the "plus+" sign, not a hyphen) and it will find all keybindings that use that binding in whole or part.  I suggest that there must be a something else also bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

---

Since this original answer, vscode introduced another way to see what other commands might be bound to given keystrokes.  With the Gear/Keyboard Shortcuts file open click on the little keyboardy icon to the right (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> with this file open) and it will indicate `Recording Keys` next to it.  Now you can literally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or whichever keybinding you are interested in) and those corresponding commands, if any, that use that keybinding will be filtered up.

Remember to disable the `Recording Keys` functionality by clicking the keyboardy icon if you want to go back to regular searching in the Keyboard Shortcuts file.

Comment: Pressing "CTRL+V" is a great idea. It showed me that with the PowerShell extension installed, an entry is present ("terminalFocus && !accessibilityModeEnabled && terminalShellType == 'pwsh'") that will hijack that keyboard combination.

Answer (score 51):

Open the keyboard shortcuts preferences by pressing **CTRL + SHIFT + P** and search for **open keyboard shortcuts file**.

Then, search for the **editor.action.clipboardPasteAction** property. In your case, it might be **CTRL+SHIFT+V**. Try changing it to Ctrl + V. Like so:

[image]

## Solution as of 2022

You could also **CTRL + SHIFT + P** and search for **open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)** and paste the following:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "when": "terminalFocus && !accessibilityModeEnabled && terminalShellType == 'pwsh'"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear"
  }
]
```

Comment: I open keybord shortcut file and find "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"  there is Ctrl+V,

Comment: Do you have another action for ctrl+v in the file?

Comment: Yes there was a conflict issue

Comment: +1 Just as a for instance of what such a conflict could look like, I have the VIm emulation plugin installed, and `extension.vim_cmd+v` had grabbed control of paste in ways I don't think it intended to. Swapped the shortcut for that command to ctrl-option-command-v in Keyboard Shortcuts (not the json version) and things are happy again.

Comment: If you want Ctrl+V to paste in a VS Code terminal as well open your keyboard shortcuts and find *workbench.action.terminal.paste* and replace it with `Ctrl+V`.

Comment: I had issues with both CTRL+V and CTRL+C I solved the ctrl+v with your method and ctrl+c by unistalling VIM plugin.

Answer (score 51):

I´ve had this problem when I enabled the "VIM" plugin for VSCode.

After uninstalling it, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this was the culprit for me too. When I disabled the plugin, reloaded VS Code, re-enabled VIM the problem was gone though.

Comment: In my case, I had "Clipboard History" installed. Disabling that seemed to work.

Comment: Yeah same here. Vim was the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I had the exact same caused by VIM plugin!

Comment: Ya except I cannot live without Vim... I wish there was a Vim plugin for everything that has a text editor

Comment: Thanks. I also had similar culprit. I had emacs extension installed. I removed it and reloaded the application. Everything worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 16):

If you install the vim extension for visual studio code and find that ctrl + x, ctrl + v .. or other shortcuts stopped working, this is because they are overwritten by **extension.vim_**

If you prefer to get those shortcuts back go to keyboard shortcuts (ctrl + shift + p, then search for open keyboard shortcuts file).

- Search for extension.vim_ and check too see if any shortcuts are
  assigned to your key combination like ctrl + v. Remove it (right click, delete).
- Also check for any other conflict by searching the file.
- Save the file, it should work now.

[image: vim keyboard extensions]

Comment: Thanks. On my mac removing `extension.vim_cmd+v` enabled pasting in insert mode, and following @unstable's advice to set `vim.useSystemClipboard` to true enabled pasting in normal mode with `p`.

Comment: This was the problem for me, but with AmVim. Strangely, although it had entries for Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v, only Copy wasn't working. Paste was fine. But deleting the AmVim Ctrl+C entry got back my shortcut.

Comment: For me I had to open ```settings.json``` and add ```"vim.useCtrlKeys": false``` to the file and then all ctrl shortcuts worked again.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem: can't CTRL+X, CTRL+C, CTRL+V on VSCode editor.
I uninstall the Vim extension and the problem is fixed.

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution, copy/paste need to work WITH vim

Answer (score 12):

For future searchers who do not have *Vim* (or any other extension) installed which is causing the issue, and who might have verified that their keyboard bindings are correct....

I have the *Salesforce Extension Pack* installed and had right-clicked on a file and run **SFDX: Deploy Source to Org**.  The deployment had errors, so in the **Panel** area (which I have at the bottom of my screen) *[see image]* I had clicked on both the *OUTPUT* and *PROBLEMS* tabs, which shifted focus away from my PowerShell *TERMINAL* tab.

My `Ctrl-V` issue was when I was trying to correct my Apex code in the **EDITOR** pane.  `Ctrl-V` was not pasting the code I had just Cut or Copied (but right-clicking and choosing *Paste* was working).

I ultimately discovered, when I changed my **Panel** focus back to my PowerShell *TERMINAL* tab, that ALL of the `Ctrl-V` pasting I had attempted had shown up after my PowerShell prompt! *["circled" in blue in image]*

---

**tl;dr**

Make sure your pasted text did not show up in your *TERMINAL* - even if it is not in focus or even if your cursor is in another **Panel** tab or in the *EDITOR*.

[image: Screenshot of portions of VS Code with EDITOR and PANEL labelled; Problems, Output and Terminal circled in orange, and the pasted text at the Terminal prompt outlined in blue.]

Comment: I can confirm that the "TERMINAL" window is the issue. For me, it wasn't even pasting it there. After I interrupted the terminal, the Ctrl + V worked fine. This is definitely a bug.

Comment: No vim, no salesforce extension pack, very common extensions working in c# I'm not sure how it resolved but opening the terminal attempt to paste, nothing, click on the clear button to clear the terminal and it switched to a Powershell window with a blinking cursor and I could suddenly paste anywhere again with ctrl-v.  It's a bug of some kind.

Answer (score 7):

From `File` > `Performance` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` > search `paste` > just try to remove or rest some `keybinding` with right click on `paste` or `default:paste`

[image]

Comment: I removed the `editor.action.clipboardPasteAction` keybinding. Not entirely sure what that command does anyway as it works without it. It'd be great to know what the difference is between `default:paste`, `paste`, `editor.action.clipboardPasteAction` and `execPaste`, as paste works without any of those keybindings.

Answer (score 7):

This problem happened to me after I left VSC update itself (currently 1.53.0). It had been converted to Shift-Insert.

Go to File->Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts. Find the `editor.action.clipboardPasteAction` and double click it, then type Ctrl+V.

Comment: Same here (current v1.55)

Answer (score 6):

If you have the Vim extension installed, you may set the vim.useSystemClipboard in the vim extension setting to true. Then you can paste the content from the clipboard by simply pressing **p** in the NORMAL mode, or use Ctrl+V in the INSERT mode.

Answer (score 4):

+1 for this - in case this helps anyone:

In my case it was only happening in the Thunder Client extension's text fields.

The culprit for me was the [Indent on Paste](https://github.com/gazugafan/vscode-indent-on-paste) extension (I'm on a Mac, so it was cmd+v instead of ctrl+v - but it fires the same event in VS Code).

I've left issue comments on the [Thunder Client](https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/issues/124) and [Indent on Paste](https://github.com/gazugafan/vscode-indent-on-paste/issues/19) repos respectively, should anyone wish to add to those.

Comment: I am on Mac too and I found this helpful. disabling the `Indent on Paste for Visual Studio Code` solved it for me at the time when I had a similar issue. Also, @webD answer is helpful too

Answer (score 4):

Look if and remove any VS Code extension :
for example - "Awesome Emacs Keymap" in my case, or any other keymaps installed.

i.e. : FILE/Preferences>/extensions and then look if any special keymap was installed

[image]

Comment: for me, the culprit was `vscodeemacs.emacs` https://github.com/VSCodeEmacs/Emacs

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was going through my extensions and disabling them one by one to find the culprit.

I had 'Paste and Indent' enabled which was messing up copying and pasting.

Just had to disable it and reload vs code.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the setting of vscode:
Settings - input:vim ctrl key - unselect: Enale some vim ctrl key commands that override otherwise common operations, like ctrl + c

Answer (score 3):

go to extensions search Emacs keymap and uninstall it

Answer (score 3):

There should something **conflicting to your any previous keyboard shortcut** 
like in **my case for Change All Occurrence: (Ctrl-C + Ctrl-A)**, vs code, confused with 
Ctrl-C for a copy shortcut to this : (Ctrl-C + Ctrl-A), so I change this to **(Shift-C + Shift-A)**, My Issue resolved.

Answer (score 3):

**Go to File>Preference>keyboard Shortcuts
Then Check for Copy and paste and enter the Ctrl+C and Ctrl+v shortcuts**

Happy Coding ;)

Answer (score 3):

None of the issues above solved this for me.  I had a key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  So when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it was in a state where it was waiting for the next key to be pressed and wouldn't do anything.

This showed up in the toolbar like so (an example):

[image]

This didn't come up in the list of keybindings when searching for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  So I found it be looking through the list.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all `cmd+v` or in windows `ctrl+v` associated keybindings.

Answer (score 3):

Open Settings > keyboard shortcuts

Search for Ctrl + c

Delete the mapping for vim.

Answer (score 2):

i have same problem
step:1

```
ctrl+shift+p
```

step:2 find

**Open keyboard shortcuts**

step:3

```
find paste
```

then you can see

```
editor.action.cliboardPasteAction
```

1. right click then changekeybinding if key wrong
2. or remove key if u found two same line(editor.action.cliboardPasteAction)

in my case is 2nd one(so i removed)

Answer (score 2):

In my case just the relaunch of VSCode solved the issue. My key bindings were fine.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, if you use remote ssh connects to a remote server and code there, ctrl + V may not be useful because that your remote server has a high balance, you can try to uninstall some useless plugins in that remote server then reload vscode.

Answer (score 2):

"Paste JSON as Code" was my offender, as well as a few other ones. I got a little extension happy there for a bit.
[image]

Comment: This isue may also be caused by the WSL pluggin. However only for the terminal. 

Visual Studio Code will automatically ask you to install the WSL plugging if it detects that you have WSL installed on your machine. However it will also change the console to accept left click to paste. It should still support CTRL + V. In my case it somehow forgot to do this. Disabeling/Enabling resolved this!

Answer (score 2):

I have disabled all extensions, and VS Code hangs for a few seconds whenever I try to paste something. This occurs with Ctrl+V, Shift+Ins and also with right click + Paste.

It hangs, and then nothing happens.

[UPDATE]
I simply reinstalled it, and that solved the issue for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31296296)

Answer (score 2):

Its easy don't worry, you need to search using `ctrl+shift+p` and find **Prefernces: Open Keyboard Shortcuts(JSON)** and add this dict

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+c",
        "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }
]
```

[image]

I thins it's very helpfull good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case everything was solved changing into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> here:

`workbench.action.terminal.paste`:

[image: workbench.action.terminal.paste]

Comment: Could you maybe show why you did the action to help the person asking the question to be able to know how to do something similar and add more settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you did everything above, but you still cannot use ctrl+c, ctrl+v to copy paste in terminal, this is the fix:

ctrl + shift + p, then search for settings.json, and click Open User Settings (JSON):

make sure you have this line in it:

```
{
...
"terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": false,
...
}
```

Then, ctrl + shift + p, then search for keyboard shortcuts, and click Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON):

Delete everything, and paste this in it:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+v",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
        "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.paste",
        "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
        "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalTextSelected || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported && terminalTextSelected"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
        "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
        "when": "terminalFocus && terminalHasBeenCreated && terminalTextSelected || terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported && terminalTextSelected"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> **For 2023 coders : **.
> If your shortcut keys such as Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V not working ( neither in code file nor in Terminal ), no need to worry

Try :
Ctrl+insert (for copy) ,
Shift+insert (for paste )

Comment: Insert is much, MUCH harder to reach then V. Not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not taking the latest text copied in clipboard,

I have removed the key bindings of copy and paste associated (insert binding) was there except the `ctrl + c` & `ctrl + v` and restarted the vs code editor

keybindings (windows) -> **ctrl + shift + p -> keyboard shortcuts**